# Show the colums that have the same 'class' to be in alphabetical order

Tags: mysql

I tried this

```
SELECT Nam , Class FROM Data order by class

    Ted-100
    Bet-100
    Carl-200
    Jenny-300
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add Nam in the order by clause, which will order Nam within each class

```
SELECT Nam , Class FROM Data order by class, Nam
```

Comment: what if i want to show the entire colums but only the ones that heve tha same class to be in alphabetical order? thanks for your help

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Do you mean what if you want to not include the class in the select but want to order by it?

Comment: no i mean that i want to include everything but only the ones that have the same class to be in alphabetical order!

Comment: @ted You're not making much sense. Perhaps a properly representative data set and desired result will clarify the situation - not as a further comment, but as an edit to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, pretty not much sure what you want, but for my understanding, you want this?

```
SELECT * FROM Data ORDER BY class, Nam;
```

By the way, you d better be more specific what you want so far to get a good answer.